# servicefabric steteless service instance count 6 when node count 5 errors out

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

we have simple stateless service with default instance count 6, deployed to local five node service fabric cluster, errors out as below at 6th instance creation. No port is given for service end point, ports are dynamic, no conflicts.

```
    System.CRM  ServiceReplicaUnplacedHealth_Secondary_9a78cf1e-252f-4b29-9d0c-10947e92928b Tue, 03 Dec 2019 12:31:37 GMT   0.00:01:05.0    132198498979714109  true    false
The Cluster Resource Manager was unable to find a placement for one or more of the Service's Replicas:
Secondary replica could not be placed due to the following constraints and properties:  
TargetReplicaSetSize: 6
Placement Constraint: N/A
Parent Service: N/A

Constraint Elimination Sequence:
Down nodes count 0, Deactivated nodes count 0, Deactivating nodes count 0
Existing Secondary Replicas eliminated 5 possible node(s) for placement -- 0/5 node(s) remain.

Nodes Eliminated By Constraints:

Existing Secondary Replicas -- Nodes with Partition's Existing Secondary Replicas/Instances:
--
FaultDomain:fd:/4 NodeName:_Node_4 NodeType:NodeType4 NodeTypeName:NodeType4 UpgradeDomain:4 Deactivation Intent/Status: None/None
FaultDomain:fd:/3 NodeName:_Node_3 NodeType:NodeType3 NodeTypeName:NodeType3 UpgradeDomain:3 Deactivation Intent/Status: None/None
FaultDomain:fd:/2 NodeName:_Node_2 NodeType:NodeType2 NodeTypeName:NodeType2 UpgradeDomain:2 Deactivation Intent/Status: None/None
FaultDomain:fd:/1 NodeName:_Node_1 NodeType:NodeType1 NodeTypeName:NodeType1 UpgradeDomain:1 Deactivation Intent/Status: None/None
FaultDomain:fd:/0 NodeName:_Node_0 NodeType:NodeType0 NodeTypeName:NodeType0 UpgradeDomain:0 Deactivation Intent/Status: None/None
```

Not sure why 6 th instance creation is failing when there is no port, application is deployed on kestrel host in reliable service.

How can we prevent this error from coming and have the 6th instance created? any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, at least not without tampering with the clusters placement constraint which can lead to a whole lot of new problems. Currently, service fabric does not allow you to have multiple instances of the same service in the same node.

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/325) regarding this very question, I suggest you read it all to get a better picture.

Comment: thanks for sharing this, so at the moment it is not possible to create more than one instance on a single partition single node. work around is to create a partition for every instance, but this deviates the concept of complete stateless instance.